# A 'C' based web application framework like Tornado or Twisted?

Tags: c, web-applications, webserver

Maybe I am looking in all the wrong places. Or maybe I might just be dumb. But I am just curious. Are there any Web application frameworks available for just the plain old `'C'` Language. Like `Tornado` and `Twisted` for python? Again, I am just Curious.

UPDATE: After keeping a tag for years, I finally found one: [kore.io](https://kore.io/) GitHub: https://github.com/jorisvink/kore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked this question 3 years ago. And I have always kept a tag on C-based framework. Now I found one which is more than worthy to mention. [kore.io](https://kore.io/) GitHub: https://github.com/jorisvink/kore

Previously, I accepted [Aidenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11769232/1235072) But I am choosing my own as accepted because this is modern and actively maintained.

Answer (score 9):

There aren't many since most web apps are not CPU bound, and involve mutations to variable sized strings, thus not playing to Cs strengths, while hitting C in one of its weakest points.

That being said:

- https://github.com/DanielWaterworth/Raphters
- https://github.com/derdewey/mongrel2_c_handler/
- http://gwan.ch/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but Aidenn is wrong. Every scripting language is written in C.  It just takes a lot more work.  C is a very strong programming language with unlimited possibilities to what you can program.
https://github.com/search?l=C&q=c%2B%2B+web+framework&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories
list of C frameworks.